# How to get to a route and id of a section in a page with several sections in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have the following link in my navbar

```
<li class="nav-item">
       <router-link to="/branding" class="nav-link">Branding</router-link>
</li>
```

It's currently working well and going to branding page which has a header section, products and services section and contact section. They all have ids of id="header", id="products_and_services" and id="contact" respectively.

Is it possible when the link is clicked it takes me to the branding page and specifically at the bottom of the page at the section with the id="contact" and not at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrollIntoView when the view is mounted

[Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

so in your mounted method

```
mounted(){
    document.getElementById('contact').scrollIntoView();
}
```

I think the way I would do it with the router is to pass a parameter and use that to scrollIntoView

```
<li class="nav-item">
       <router-link :to="{ name: 'home', params: { scrollTo: contact }}">Branding</router-link>
</li>
```

Then in mounted:

```
mounted(){
   document.getElementById(this.$route.query.scrollTo).scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Hello, this sheds some light though I have dpne a mistake in my question. It's the home page that has the  header section, products and services section and contact section. 

Branding page is another page independently. So when I'm on branding page and click on either Product $ Services or Contact on the navbar then it it takes me to the home page. I'd like when I click on Contact then it not only takes me to the home page but also to the element with the id="contact"

Should I make this changes on the question or ask the question a fresh. Kindly advice...

Comment: @AlphyGacheru I updated my answer. I hope that helps.